# Converting NSDate to NSString and back won't return the same date

Tags: ios, ios8, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I created category extensions to extend both `NSDate` and `NSString` to support easy way to convert `NSDate` to `NSString` and vice versa. When I ran a little test, the dates seemed to match but trying to compare did not. 
Here is how I convert `NSDate` to `NSString`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self];
```

And here is how I get it back to `NSDate`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
return [dateFormatter dateFromString:self];
```

This is the test I ran:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@", now); // 2014-12-25 21:59:45 +0000
NSString *dateString = [now stringRepresentation];
NSLog(@"%@", dateString); // 2014-12-25T23:59:45+0200
NSDate *converted = [dateString dateRepresentation];
NSLog(@"%@", converted); // 2014-12-25 21:59:45 +0000
BOOL result1 = [now isEqualToDate:converted]; // false
BOOL result2 = [now compare:converted] == NSOrderedSame; // false
NSComparisonResult result3 = [now compare:converted]; // NSOrderedDescending
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you **lose the sub-second accuracy in conversion**.

When creating `[NSDate now]`, the sub-second information is kept in `NSDate` object. Then you convert it to string that does not keep that information, and after the conversion back it's simply gone.

As the documentation for `isEqualToDate:` states:

> This method detects sub-second differences between dates. If you want to compare dates with a less fine granularity, use timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the two dates.

The same goes for `compare`:

> This method detects sub-second differences between dates. If you want to compare dates with a less fine granularity, use timeIntervalSinceDate: to compare the two dates.

There are at least three possible solutions:

- use `timeIntervalSinceDate:` for comparison to ignore the sub-seconds
- use string representations that is able to keep the sub-seconds
- roll your own comparison method that will compare with the accuracy that you like - the mentioned categories are the best place to add that.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I created my own comparison methods and it works as expected.